# .forEach method applying update to all items in array instead of individual item

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making a small exercise for some students of mine where I am automating a kind of 10 pin bowling game I have put it into a JsBin here https://jsbin.com/qilizo/edit?html,js,output. I don't know whether I am tired, stupid or it's just because I am working on a national holiday but something has me puzzled. When i start the game I prompt the user to set up a number of desired players. This automatically produces an object array of Players like so:

```
[{score: Array[10], spareCount: 0, strikeCount: 0, username: "Player 1"}, ...]
```

Now later I allow the user to play frames where each Player in our array has two throws... I collect the score and add it to the certain player's score array. However when I try to perform this action using a .forEach method the score I generate is applied to all items in my Players array (play the game and see). I have put my code in a jsBin and the problem is on line 109 :  `a.score[currentFrame - 1] = playFrame();`

I have tried to amend my code but I can't work out why the current (or last) frame score is being applied to all Player objects! If you can understand my syntax error and explain why I would be most appreciative. Play the game (just click the button after setting the player numbers) and you will see what I mean...

Snippet:

```js
var players,
    currentFrame = 0,
    currentThrow = 0;

// helper functions
// Accurate isNumber function... Thank you Crockford (see JavaScript: The Good Parts)
function isNumber(value) {
    return typeof(value === 'number') && isFinite(value);
}

function frameStyle(k) {

    var returnCssClass,
        k = k + 1;

    if (k < currentFrame) {
        returnCssClass = 'played-frame';
    } else if (k === currentFrame) {
        returnCssClass = 'current-frame';
    } else {
        returnCssClass = null;
    }

    return returnCssClass;

}

function setUpPlayers(num) {

    var tempArray = [],
        tempName = 'Player ',
        emptyScores = Array(10).fill([-1, -1]); // set default to -1 as a rubbish player may hit no pins!

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        tempArray.push({
            username: tempName + (i + 1),
            score: emptyScores,
            strikeCount: 0,
            spareCount: 0
        }); // the way I have named the tempName is technically an antipattern!
    }

    return tempArray;
}

function getTotals(scores) {

    var totalScore = scores.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b.reduce(function(c, d) {
            return (c + (c + ((d > 0) ? d : 0)));
        }, 0);
    }, 0);

    return totalScore;
}

function displayScore(score) {

    // toDo reformat!
    var formatScore = score.map(function(a, b) {
        if (a === -1) {
            a = '-';
        } else if (a === 10) {
            a = 'X';
        }
        return a;
    });

    return formatScore;
}

function createGrid() {

    // If only I was using ES6 I could have multi line support!
    var playerLen = players.length,
        scoresLen = players[0].score.length;
    boards = '<div class="score-board">' +
        '<!-- one row for each player -->';
    // need to loop this through the players...
    for (var i = 0; i < playerLen; i++) {
        boards += '<div class="row">' +
            '<!-- first cell is the name -->' +
            '<div class="name">' + players[i].username + '</div>';
        // need to loop this with the users scores
        for (var k = 0; k < scoresLen; k++) {
            boards += '<div class="game ' + frameStyle(k) + ' ">' + displayScore(players[i].score[k]) + '</div>';
        }
        // don't forget the total
        boards += '<div class="player-total">' + getTotals(players[i].score) + '</div>';
        boards += '</div>';

    }
    boards += '</div>';
    boards += '<div>Current Frame: ' + currentFrame + '</div>';
    boards += '<button type="button" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>';
    // fill the holder....
    document.getElementById('boardHolder').innerHTML = boards;
}

function startGame() {

    if (currentFrame >= 10) {
        announceWinner();
    } else {
        currentFrame++;

        // do the throws for Each Player!
        players.forEach(function(a, b) {
            a.score[currentFrame - 1] = playFrame();
        });

        // update the grid
        createGrid();
        // recurrrrrrsion....
        //startGame();

    }
}

function throwBall(pinsStanding) {
    // i know it isn't a ball
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (pinsStanding + 1));
}

function playFrame() {
    // here we just create the array and determine if we have a strike or a spare!
    var pinsStanding = 10,
        frameScore = [],
        frameThrows = 2,
        pinsDown;

        for(var i = 0; i < frameThrows; i++) {

            pinsDown = throwBall(pinsStanding);
            pinsStanding = pinsStanding - pinsDown;

            // if it is the pinsStanding = 0 and it is the first throw - a strike!
            if(pinsStanding === 0 && i === 1) {
                pinsStanding = 10;
                frameThrows = 3;
            }

            // what if it is a spare?
            frameScore.push(pinsDown);
        }

        return frameScore;
}

function announceWinner() {

}

// kick it all off!!!
window.onload = function() {
    // lets get some users....
    players = prompt('Please enter the NUMBER of players?', 2);

    // check we have a number...
    if (isNumber(players)) {
        players = setUpPlayers(players);
        createGrid();
    }
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* classes */
.score-board {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.row {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.row:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.row > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.game {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.name {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.player-total {
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #d5eabb;
}

.played-frame {
    background-color: #aee1e8;
}

.current-frame {
    background-color: #ffc0cb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Let's go bowling!</h1>

  <div id="boardHolder">
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the bin!
https://jsbin.com/qilizo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `Array(10).fill([-1, -1])` inside for loop, because otherwise all objects will share the same score array:

```
function setUpPlayers(num) {

    var tempArray = [],
        tempName = 'Player '; 

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        tempArray.push({
            username: tempName + (i + 1),
            score: Array(10).fill([-1, -1]),// set default to -1 as a rubbish player may hit no pins!
            strikeCount: 0,
            spareCount: 0
        }); // the way I have named the tempName is technically an antipattern!
    }

    return tempArray;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/yeyupiteyu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript objects are passed by reference, and since array is an object, if you declare `emptyScores` outside the loop and then assign it to every element of the array, all elements will share the same score array.

You have make new `emptyScores` array for each element, so you have to declare it inside the loop:

```
var tempArray = [],
    tempName = 'Player ';

for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    var emptyScores = Array(10).fill([-1, -1]);
    tempArray.push({
        username: tempName + (i + 1),
        score: emptyScores,
        strikeCount: 0,
        spareCount: 0
    });
}
```